# Lightning App: single app vs app-per-page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Suppose we have instance dealership. We are going to have List/New/Edit View pages.

I am inclined to have single dealership.app lightning app and change/show List View/Edit/New components dynamically when navigating between List/New/Edit View.

Are there pros for having separate apps for each of List/Edit/New View components and navigate between lightning apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you hit the Lightning App URL, there is a cost in startup of the app itself, including a download of the aggregated JS and CSS resources for that app and the JSON which represents the component markup in metadata.

Whereas if you keep the same app running and then navigate between components, there is simply some JSON that gets sent to the client, and perhaps any XHR requests.

You could try, but I suspect you will find performance characteristics will not be very user friendly using the architecture/navigation you suggest.